# scrolltoTop not working in Animated.scrollView

Tags: react-native

It is working fine with ScrollView but not working with Animated.ScrollView
"undefined is not a function"

```html
<Animated.ScrollView scrollEventThrottle={1} ref="_scrollView">
    {content}
</Animated.ScrollView>
            
<Button title='Button' onPress={() => { this.refs._scrollView.scrollTo(0); }}/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to get the actual `ref` of the `Animated.ScrollView` component:

`this.refs._scrollView.getNode().scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0})`

**Update**: Use `getNode()` instead of accessing `_component` directly as it should be treated as an internal field.

Answer (score -1):

`scrollTo()` accepts and object as a parameter, where object contains: `{x:<number>, y:<number>, animated:<boolean>}`

You also have to make sure that refs are really set. That's probably the reason why you're getting **undefined is not a function**.

So, in order to scroll top, I'd do it like:

```
onPress={() => {
  if (this.refs._scrollView) {
    this.refs._scrollView.scrollTo({x:0, y:0});
  }
}}
```

Comment: Did you tested it with Animated.ScrollView? Because it is not working.

Comment: Keep in mind that without Animated my example is working